# Border 1px for image with border:0; without js

Tags: html, css, border

I have a banner with 1000px of width and 250px of height.

```
<a href="#">
   <img width="1000" height="250" border="0" src="http://oboshto.ru/upme/shits/banner1000.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

and I can't edit the image and link code. But i can add custom code before and after banner.

How can I set 1px banner border?

Look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/aNzGM/1/)

My code doesn't look good (look at *border-bottom and border-right*, but banner size is right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your border is there, the reason it's not on the right and bottom is your container has `width:998px; height:248px;` but your image has `width="1000" height="250"` either add two more pixels to your container so that the image isn't breaking out or set the container to `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: no because the image is breaking over the container, setting `overflow:hidden` will simply hide the extra 2pxs of the height and width on the image and show the border: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNzGM/13/)

Answer (score 0):

This is code that i have changed 
use css

```
img { border: 1px solid #fff000; }
```

and code

```
<div style="width:998px; height:248px;">

    <!-- CAN'T EDIT THIS BLOCKS FROM -->
    <a href="#">  
        <img width="1000" height="250" border="0" src="http://oboshto.ru/upme/shits/banner1000.jpg" alt=""></img>
    </a>
    <!-- TO -->

</div> <!--  << editable -->
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5JjQW/ check this code you can set with

```
    <div style="position: absolute;border: 1px solid #f00;width:998px; padding:2px; height:248px;">


<a href="#">  
<img width="1000" height="250" border="0" src="http://oboshto.ru/upme/shits/banner1000.jpg" alt=""></img>
</a>


</div>
```